# [Error: Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12 ']

Tags: macos, appium, siri

Environment : macOX siri, 
appium: 1.5.3

I am not able run `appium`. Please help, How to fixed this issue?

```
appium doctor has not worked. 
Error :
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
[Error: Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12
```

Appium Logs:

```
    `Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' appium/build/lib/main.js --debug-log-spacing --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "7.0" --app "/Users/tanmoyray/Desktop/veiculu.apk" --avd "test_7.0" --app-pkg "com.senrysa.parkingplace" --app-activity "com.facebook.LoginActivity" --device-name "Moto"

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.3

[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   debugLogSpacing: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '7.0'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'Moto'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/tanmoyray/Desktop/veiculu.apk'
[Appium]   appPackage: 'com.senrysa.parkingplace'
[Appium]   appActivity: 'com.facebook.LoginActivity'
[Appium]   avd: 'test_7.0'
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --platform-name => --default-capabilities '{"platformName":"Android"}'
[Appium]   --platform-version => --default-capabilities '{"platformVersion":"7.0"}'
[Appium]   --automation-name => --default-capabilities '{"automationName":"Appium"}'
[Appium]   --device-name => --default-capabilities '{"deviceName":"Moto"}'
[Appium]   --app => --default-capabilities '{"app":"/Users/tanmoyray/Desktop/veiculu.apk"}'
[Appium]   --app-pkg => --default-capabilities '{"appPackage":"com.senrysa.parkingplace"}'
[Appium]   --app-activity => --default-capabilities '{"appActivity":"com.facebook.LoginActivity"}'
[Appium]   --avd => --default-capabilities '{"avd":"test_7.0"}'
[Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden by desired capabilities:
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '7.0'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'Moto'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/tanmoyray/Desktop/veiculu.apk'
[Appium]   appPackage: 'com.senrysa.parkingplace'
[Appium]   appActivity: 'com.facebook.LoginActivity'
[Appium]   avd: 'test_7.0'

[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 41 ms - 83 

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 25 ms - 83 

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 22 ms - 83 

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getSessions() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getSessions() result: []

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 4 ms - 40 

[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","appPackage":"com.senrysa.parkingplace","newCommandTimeout":"7200","app":"/Users/tanmoyray/Desktop/veiculu.apk","platformVersion":"7.0","deviceName":"Moto","automationName":"Appium"}}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformName":"Android",...

[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   appPackage: 'com.senrysa.parkingplace'
[Appium]   newCommandTimeout: '7200'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/tanmoyray/Desktop/veiculu.apk'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '7.0'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'Moto'
[Appium]   automationName: 'Appium'
[Appium]   appActivity: 'com.facebook.LoginActivity'
[Appium]   avd: 'test_7.0'

[BaseDriver] Capability 'newCommandTimeout' changed from string ('7200') to integer (7200). This may cause unexpected behavior

[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 135df2ce-cc52-43c8-95aa-9a1a35d6fb19
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version

[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_91

[ADB] Checking whether adb is present

[ADB] Using adb from /Users/tanmoyray/library/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

[debug] [ADB] Trying to find test_7.0 emulator

[debug] [ADB] Getting connected emulators

[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...

[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected

[debug] [ADB] 1 emulator(s) connected

[debug] [ADB] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
[debug] [ADB] Getting running emulator port

[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device created

[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device ready

[debug] [ADB] Telnet command got response: Nexus_S_API_24

[debug] [ADB] Emulator test_7.0 not running
[debug] [ADB] Launching Emulator with AVD test_7.0, launchTimeout60000 ms and readyTimeout 60000 ms
[ADB] Checking whether emulator is present

.
.
.

[debug] [ADB] Trying to find test_7.0 emulator

[debug] [ADB] Getting connected emulators
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] 1 emulator(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
[debug] [ADB] Getting running emulator port
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device created
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device ready
[debug] [ADB] Telnet command got response: Nexus_S_API_24
[debug] [ADB] Emulator test_7.0 not running

[debug] [ADB] Trying to find test_7.0 emulator

[debug] [ADB] Getting connected emulators
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] 1 emulator(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
[debug] [ADB] Getting running emulator port
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device created
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device ready
[debug] [ADB] Telnet command got response: Nexus_S_API_24
[debug] [ADB] Emulator test_7.0 not running

[debug] [ADB] Trying to find test_7.0 emulator

[debug] [ADB] Getting connected emulators
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...

[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected

[ADB] Error: Could not find test_7.0 emulator.
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/system-calls.js:325:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 [Error: Could not find test_7.0 emulator.]

[debug] [ADB] 1 emulator(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
[debug] [ADB] Getting running emulator port
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device created
[debug] [ADB] Socket connection to device ready
[debug] [ADB] Telnet command got response: Nexus_S_API_24
[debug] [ADB] Emulator test_7.0 not running
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[AndroidDriver] Cannot shut down Android driver; it has already shut down
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 64352 ms - 216 

[ADB] Error: Error getting AVD with retry. Original error: Could not find test_7.0 emulator.
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/system-calls.js:327:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 [Error: Error getting AVD with retry. Original error: Could not find test_7.0 emulator.]
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error getting AVD with retry. Original error: Could not find test_7.0 emulator.
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/system-calls.js:327:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 95 ms - 83 
`
```

Comment: The way to solve it is in this question: [How to fix error “Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12 '” from Appium](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40168992/2334082)

Answer (score -1):

1. `npm uninstall -g appium-doctor`
2. `npm install -g appium-doctor`

Comment: Try to explain your answer instead of just copy/pasting code. That way you can ensure everyone learns from your experience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!