# How to fix error "Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12 '" from Appium

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I installed appium-1.5.3.dmg But when I click the stethoscope button the Appium is show error :

```
 ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
[Error: Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12
']
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**It' worked for me.**

You can config file by this command:

- grep -rl "Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output:" /Applications/Appium.app/

[image]

- Terminal will show :
  /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/build/lib/system.js
  /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/system.js
  /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium-support/build/lib/system.js
  /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium-support/lib/system.js
- Use command vim and config each file.

### Example

```
vim /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/build/lib/system.js
```

[image]

Config file:

[image]

1. Change From ->

   `case 10:
       _arr = ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11'];
       _i = 0;`

   To ->

   `case 10:
       _arr = ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11','10.12'];
       _i = 0;`

---

```
vim /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/system.js
```

[image]

Config file:

[image]

1. Change From ->

   `try {
   stdout = (await exec('sw_vers', ['-productVersion'])).stdout;
   }`

   To ->

   `try {
   stdout = (await exec('sw_vers', ['-productVersion'])).stdout.trim();
   }`
2. Change From ->

   `for (let v of ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11']) {
   if (stdout.indexOf(v) === 0) { return v; }
   }`

   To ->

   `for (let v of ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11','10.12']) {
   if (stdout.indexOf(v) === 0) { return v; }
   }`

---

```
vim /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium-support/build/lib/system.js
```

[image]

Config file:

[image]

1. Change From ->

   `case 10:
       _arr = ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11'];
       _i = 0;`

   To ->

   `case 10:
       _arr = ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11','10.12'];
       _i = 0;`

---

```
vim /Applications/Appium.app//Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium-support/lib/system.js
```

[image]

Config file:

[image]

1. Change From ->

   `try {
   stdout = (await exec('sw_vers', ['-productVersion'])).stdout;
   }`

   To ->

   `try {
   stdout = (await exec('sw_vers', ['-productVersion'])).stdout.trim();
   }`
2. Change From ->

   `for (let v of ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11']) {
   if (stdout.indexOf(v) === 0) { return v; }
   }`

   To ->

   `for (let v of ['10.8', '10.9', '10.10', '10.11','10.12']) {
   if (stdout.indexOf(v) === 0) { return v; }
   }`

**Click start the stethoscope button**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That was a great help. Saved my time.

Comment: This would have never occurred to me. Excellent answer.

Comment: I followed this example, but the same error message is presented when I run 'appium-doctor'. I have macOS High Sierra installed (10.3), so I used same approach. Any idea?

Comment: Any one who can help me how to edit the Config file?

Comment: To use vim and edit config file, please follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5764079/3659227

Answer (score 0):

I went through the above steps even though I saw that it's been [fixed](https://github.com/appium/appium-support/pull/54/files) by appium already.

Just run:

```
npm install appium-doctor -g
```

to update appium-doctor itself, then run:

```
appium-doctor
```

again to see it work.

#### Before and after fix:

[image]