# mac os sierra not configring appium for 10.12.1

Tags: ios, macos, operating-system, macos-sierra, appium-ios

This is the error i got when i run APM Doctor.

I have followed some steps using this  link:
[How to fix error "Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12 '" from Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129794/how-to-fix-error-could-not-detect-mac-os-x-version-from-sw-vers-output-10-12/40168992#40168992)

This was the result.

[image]

please some help me to solve the issue. Showing step by step screenshots would be greatly appreciable for my easy understanding
Thanks

Comment: which version of appium are you using ?

Comment: i am facing the same issue i am using Appium Version 1.5.3 (Ara). if you find any solution please post here

Comment: Same question with solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129794/how-to-fix-error-could-not-detect-mac-os-x-version-from-sw-vers-output-10-12