# Appium : [Error: Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12.2 ']

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am new to Appium. I am using 1.5.3 on my mac. I am getting below error. Can someone please help.

> Error: Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12.2'

tried the solution from here. It didnt help [How to fix error "Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12 '" from Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129794/how-to-fix-error-could-not-detect-mac-os-x-version-from-sw-vers-output-10-12/40168992#40168992)

Comment: which version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix error "Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw\_vers output: '10.12 '" from Appium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129794/how-to-fix-error-could-not-detect-mac-os-x-version-from-sw-vers-output-10-12)