# Appium doctor shows syntax error in Mac OS 10.12.4

Tags: ios, appium

First time I got another error and follow the steps in below link

[How to fix error "Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12 '" from Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129794/how-to-fix-error-could-not-detect-mac-os-x-version-from-sw-vers-output-10-12/40168992#40168992)

After that Appium Doctor shows this error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number

at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)

at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)

at Module.load (module.js:357:32)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)

at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

at require (internal/module.js:16:19)

at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:1:20)

at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)

at Module.load (module.js:357:32)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)

at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

at require (internal/module.js:16:19)

at Object.<anonymous> (lib/xcode.js:1:42)

at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.